# How to make a boat symbol in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I would like to make a motorboat/boat/raft/ship symbol in LaTex but cannot find a command for one. I know there is `\Plane` in `bbding` dingbats which gives the symbol for plane. But I dont see anything for boat or similar.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: why do you need a font character, rather than simply `\includegraphics{boat}` for any suitable image?

Comment: There is `\PHship` in `phaistos`

Answer (score 17):

Can we cheat?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\myboat}{%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.0000165em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.08em, y=0.08em, xscale=0.25, yscale=-0.25, inner
                            sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=cyan!40] (99.9880,49.1240) .. controls (97.9470,49.1240) and (95.9760,48.6600) ..
  (94.2380,47.8720) .. controls (92.4520,47.0370) and (90.4350,46.5500) ..
  (88.3470,46.5500) .. controls (86.2380,46.5500) and (84.2200,47.0370) ..
  (82.4350,47.8720) .. controls (80.6720,48.6600) and (78.7240,49.1240) ..
  (76.6840,49.1240) .. controls (74.6660,49.1240) and (72.6950,48.6600) ..
  (70.9560,47.8720) .. controls (69.1710,47.0370) and (67.1530,46.5500) ..
  (65.0430,46.5500) .. controls (62.9560,46.5500) and (60.9390,47.0370) ..
  (59.1530,47.8720) .. controls (57.3910,48.6600) and (55.4430,49.1240) ..
  (53.4030,49.1240) .. controls (51.3620,49.1240) and (49.4140,48.6600) ..
  (47.6740,47.8720) .. controls (45.8890,47.0370) and (43.8710,46.5500) ..
  (41.7620,46.5500) .. controls (39.6520,46.5500) and (37.6570,47.0370) ..
  (35.8720,47.8720) .. controls (34.1100,48.6600) and (32.1620,49.1240) ..
  (30.1220,49.1240) .. controls (28.0820,49.1240) and (26.1570,48.6600) ..
  (24.4170,47.8720) .. controls (22.6080,47.0370) and (20.6140,46.5500) ..
  (18.5040,46.5500) .. controls (16.3940,46.5500) and (14.4000,47.0370) ..
  (12.5910,47.8720) .. controls (10.8520,48.6600) and (8.9040,49.1240) ..
  (6.8630,49.1240) -- (6.8630,40.5210) .. controls (8.9040,40.5210) and
  (10.8510,40.0570) .. (12.5910,39.2680) .. controls (14.4000,38.4570) and
  (16.3940,37.9700) .. (18.5040,37.9700) .. controls (20.6140,37.9700) and
  (22.6080,38.4570) .. (24.4170,39.2680) .. controls (26.1560,40.0570) and
  (28.0810,40.5210) .. (30.1220,40.5210) .. controls (32.1630,40.5210) and
  (34.1100,40.0570) .. (35.8720,39.2680) .. controls (37.6570,38.4570) and
  (39.6520,37.9700) .. (41.7620,37.9700) .. controls (43.8710,37.9700) and
  (45.8890,38.4570) .. (47.6740,39.2680) .. controls (49.4130,40.0570) and
  (51.3620,40.5210) .. (53.4030,40.5210) .. controls (55.4430,40.5210) and
  (57.3910,40.0570) .. (59.1530,39.2680) .. controls (60.9380,38.4570) and
  (62.9560,37.9700) .. (65.0430,37.9700) .. controls (67.1530,37.9700) and
  (69.1710,38.4570) .. (70.9560,39.2680) .. controls (72.6940,40.0570) and
  (74.6660,40.5210) .. (76.6840,40.5210) .. controls (78.7240,40.5210) and
  (80.6720,40.0570) .. (82.4350,39.2680) .. controls (84.2200,38.4570) and
  (86.2380,37.9700) .. (88.3470,37.9700) .. controls (90.4350,37.9700) and
  (92.4510,38.4570) .. (94.2380,39.2680) .. controls (95.9760,40.0570) and
  (97.9470,40.5210) .. (99.9880,40.5210) -- (99.9880,49.1240) -- cycle;
\protect\path[fill=gray!30] (76.5680,13.1940) -- (93.4960,14.5150) -- (92.2210,5.8660)
   -- (79.7910,4.9850) .. controls (76.4300,4.8230) and (76.9160,8.1850) ..
  (76.9160,8.1850) -- (76.5680,13.1940) -- cycle;
\protect\path[fill=gray!30] (45.1720,11.2230) .. controls (48.2790,11.2230) and
  (50.7830,8.7190) .. (50.7830,5.6120) .. controls (50.7830,2.5050) and (48.2790,0.0000) .. (45.1720,0.0000) .. controls (42.0650,0.0000) and (39.5610,2.5050) ..
  (39.5610,5.6120) .. controls (39.5610,8.7190) and (42.0640,11.2230) ..
  (45.1720,11.2230) -- cycle;
\protect\path[fill=gray!30] (10.5290,32.8460) .. controls (11.2480,32.6380) and (11.9440,32.3600) ..
  (12.5930,32.0580) .. controls (14.4020,31.2230) and (16.3960,30.7360) ..
  (18.5060,30.7360) .. controls (20.6160,30.7360) and (22.6100,31.2230) ..
  (24.4190,32.0580) .. controls (26.1580,32.8460) and (28.0830,33.3100) ..
  (30.1240,33.3100) .. controls (32.1650,33.3100) and (34.1120,32.8460) ..
  (35.8740,32.0580) .. controls (37.6590,31.2230) and (39.6540,30.7360) ..
  (41.7640,30.7360) .. controls (43.8730,30.7360) and (45.8910,31.2230) ..
  (47.6760,32.0580) .. controls (49.4150,32.8460) and (51.3640,33.3100) ..
  (53.4050,33.3100) .. controls (55.4450,33.3100) and (57.3930,32.8460) ..
  (59.1550,32.0580) .. controls (60.9400,31.2230) and (62.9580,30.7360) ..
  (65.0450,30.7360) .. controls (67.1550,30.7360) and (69.1730,31.2230) ..
  (70.9580,32.0580) .. controls (72.6960,32.8460) and (74.6680,33.3100) ..
  (76.6860,33.3100) .. controls (78.7260,33.3100) and (80.6740,32.8460) ..
  (82.4370,32.0580) .. controls (84.2220,31.2230) and (86.2400,30.7360) ..
  (88.3490,30.7360) .. controls (90.4370,30.7360) and (92.4530,31.2230) ..
  (94.2400,32.0580) .. controls (95.9780,32.8460) and (97.9270,33.3100) ..
  (99.9670,33.3100) -- (98.0660,17.9710) -- (27.6910,12.0810) --
  (38.3110,1.3680) -- (33.6500,0.9510) -- (23.0500,11.6870) -- (0.0010,9.7860)
  .. controls (-0.1380,17.6460) and (8.6270,30.7130) .. (10.5290,32.8460) --
  (10.5290,32.8460) -- cycle;

\protect\end{tikzpicture}}
~}

\begin{document}

This is my boat \myboat

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I'm not even sure I could draw that in Inkscape to begin with. +1 for skill (unless of course you just found it on the internet… XD)

Comment: That code begs for cleaning up ;)

Comment: Why not `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of all the `\protect`?

Answer (score 11):

Just found a dugout:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\faPhone}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\faPhone}\\[-14.5pt]
\scalebox{0.4}{\faUser}\\[-4pt]
\widetilde{}\quad\widetilde{}\quad\widetilde{}\quad\widetilde{}\\[-10pt]
\widetilde{}\quad\widetilde{}\quad\widetilde{}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**:

Here some earnest symbols:

The font [Quivira](http://www.quivira-font.com/) contains a sail boat and a ferry. The font [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) contains them also as well as a speedboat, a ship, and a rowing boat:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{quivira.otf}
    \symbol{"26F5}\symbol{"26F4}

    \setmainfont{symbola.ttf}
    \symbol{"26F5}\symbol{"26F4}\symbol{"1F6A4}\symbol{"1F6A2}\symbol{"1F6A3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[Unicode 7.0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/version/7.0/index.htm) gives us two more symbols. A passenger ship and a motor boat:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \setmainfont{symbola.ttf}
    \symbol{"1F6F3}\symbol{"1F6E5}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Credits to "Symbol 1" for mentioning the package `phaistos`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phaistos}

\begin{document}
\PHship
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this what they mean by *mobile data stream*?

Comment: @percusse haha, yes, absolutely!

Comment: Now, I see that I met a true talent on graphics: I would never think that a telephone is a boat en-face.

Answer (score 4):

The Unicode symbol for a sailboat is U+26F5, so \char"26F5 should work in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  If you have an emoji font that contains this glyph, you might want to make an alias for that font with \newfontface from fontspec.  MWE (if you have Symbola):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface\emojifont{Symbola} % Or another font containing emoji
\newcommand\boat{{\emojifont \char"26F5}}

\begin{document}
This is my boat: \boat.  Isn't it grand?
\end{document}
```