How to eneable these characters in fontspec (knockout arrows)
How can I eneable the following characters with fontspec? I want to use the arrow with the rounded circle. Thanks in advance,


These are Unicode chars U+2B88, U+2B89, U+2B8A, and U+2B8B, but none of my local unicode fonts actually defines the glyph...

I own a font which includes these characters. I just want to know which command of fontspec I have to activate in order to get the characters. By default, the normal arrows (on the left) appear.

Then I think this answer is what you want.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198861/15036

Cheers @Thruston!

I've voted to close as a duplicate then...

@Thruston isn't there a better duplicate? that one is about making a symbol, whereas this one is about using one. some of the answers are relevant, but e.g. creating a symbol in tikz is very different, so I can't see how this is a duplicate of that question.

@cfr it was this specific answer to that question that was relevant, I agree that the other question is slightly different.

@Thruston it gets complicated when an answer to a different question is also an answer to the new one. but I think (?) officially (?!) questions are duplicates rather than anything to do with answers. or am I misremembering?

You could use the fontawesome5 package:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}

\begin{document} 

\faArrowCircleDown
\faArrowCircleUp
\faArrowCircleLeft
\faArrowCircleRight
  
\end{document}



You find a font that has the glyphs.
On my system, Symbola (which is freely available, as far as I know) has them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\Symbola}{Symbola}

\NewDocumentCommand{\whiteinblackleft}{}{{\Symbola\symbol{"2B88}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\whiteinblackup}{}{{\Symbola\symbol{"2B89}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\whiteinblackright}{}{{\Symbola\symbol{"2B8A}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\whiteinblackdown}{}{{\Symbola\symbol{"2B8B}}}

\begin{document}

Normal text 
\whiteinblackleft \whiteinblackup 
\whiteinblackright \whiteinblackdown

\end{document}


